# Add \dot{\tilde{\mathbb{x}}} to a document

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath, math-operators

I am trying to add a tilde onto a dot on top of a bold value in latex. Something like this:
`\dot{\tilde{\mathbb{x}}}` but instead it is producing:

[image]

Comment: Your code works fine for me, so could you please provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/)? In particular, how is defined `\mathbb{x}`?

Comment: Do you mean `\mathbf`, perhaps? However, if I try `$\dot{\tilde{\mathbf{x}}}$` I get the expected result.